# Windows awk-style functionality in batch script

Tags: windows, batch, awk

I want to extract a word from a line in a test file on a Windows server, using batch script. The line of text is as follows;

```
 CURRENTHEIGHT(9182)     TEMPERATURE(1234)
```

I would like to extract the number 9182 and 1234 which I need for some further computation.

How do I do this in a batch script?

Thanks

Comment: Please note that https://superuser.com is not a free script/code writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (include the scripts/code you are already using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [How do I ask a good question?](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Hints: [findstr](http://ss64.com/nt/findstr.html) - Search for strings in files. [for /f](http://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html) - Loop command against the results of another command.

Comment: In Windows, you use awk exactly as in other OS. However, awk is not installed by default; you need to find and download a Windows package of posix utilities.

Answer (score 1):

If using Gnu-awk gawk is not an option you'll need a combination of the already mentioned `for /f` and `findstr` which has limited RegEx capabilities.
for /f will ignore leading delimiters and treat consecutive delimiters as only one. To parse your sample line you need the delimiters `()` and `space`. The required numbers are tokens `2` and `4`, tokens `1` and `3` are acceptable variable names. A RegEx for the line could be `"CURRENTHEIGHT([0-9][0-9]*).*TEMPERATURE([0-9][0-9]*)"`  I DID say linmited ;-). The first used for variable `%%A` corresponds to the first token; `%%D` to the fourth one. To put all this together:

```
:: ExtractHeightTemp.cmd ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
@echo off
Set File=C:\Test\test.txt
for /f "tokens=1-4 delims=() " %%A in (
  'findstr /i "CURRENTHEIGHT([0-9][0-9]*).*TEMPERATURE([0-9][0-9]*)" "%File%"'
) do Set _%%A=%%B&Set _%%C=%%D
Set _
Pause
```

The batch produces this output here:

```
> ExtractHeightTemp.cmd
_CURRENTHEIGHT=9182
_TEMPERATURE=1234
```